# Set .properties file to testng.xml

Tags: java, testng

I have a **data.properties** file with the following lines :

```
data.login=login
data.password=password
```

and I have a simple test(with testng):

```
@Test
@Parameters({"data.login","data.password"})
public void testSimpleExample(String login, String password) throws Exception {
    Assert.assertTrue(login.equals("login"));
    Assert.assertTrue(password.equals("password"));
}
```

In testng.xml file I can write next strings :

```
<parameter name="data.login" value="login" />
<parameter name="data.password" value="password" />
```

but I want to use my **data.properties** file. Can I somehow set this file into testng.xml and use parameters from this properties file ? Of course **without** using next code :

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(....);
    ....
properties.getProperty("data.login");
```

Comment: you need to do it manually, xml can be contains the name of file and you read it using properties .

Comment: ok, but for what needs  @Parameters annotation?  For example, if I have 100 parameters, should I put all of this into testng.xml like separate line.. ?

Comment: Where are you finding documentation that supports the @Parameters annotation for XML config values? And where are you getting the `<parameter />` syntax from? The documentation I found here http://junitext.sourceforge.net/tutorial.html, says you must annotate a constructor for initialization of the xml params, like so: @XMLParameters("/path/to/testing.xml"). Also, I don't think the JunitExt lib supports importing properties into the testing.xml file from a properties file. Looks like you should either load the properties in the Junit constructor, or define them in xml.

Comment: @squarephoenix - I believe the Test Runner here is TestNG and not JUnit.

Comment: @Krishnan Mahadevan  you are right it's about TestNG not JUnit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another way of doing it, if you don't want to make use of the data provider approach that @juherr has called out.

Properties file represents a Key/Value pair, so essentially its a map. So you do the following :

1. Ensure you are using TestNG v6.11 (or) higher.
2. Use the `@Parameters` annotation as if you are going to get the values from your TestNG suite xml file.
3. Build a `org.testng.IAlterSuiteListener` implementation wherein you read your properties file, extract out the map, and then inject this map as parameters into your `XmlSuite` object.
4. You wire in this listener that you created in (3) either via the `<listeners>` tag in your suite xml (or) via a Service loader mechanism.

Now you can continue to work with the `@Parameters` annotation, but all of your properties are injected dynamically.

Here's a sample of all this in action.

**TestClass looks like below**

```
package com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn46224926;

import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestClass {
    @Test
    @Parameters("name")
    public void testMethod(String name) {
        System.err.println("Hello " + name);
    }
}
```

The `IAlterSuiteListener` implementation looks like below:

```
package com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn46224926;

import org.testng.IAlterSuiteListener;
import org.testng.xml.XmlSuite;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

public class PropertyInjectorListener implements IAlterSuiteListener {
    @Override
    public void alter(List<XmlSuite> suites) {
        XmlSuite suite = suites.get(0);
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            properties.load(new FileReader("src/test/resources/46224926/qn46224926.properties"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> each : properties.entrySet()) {
            params.put(each.getKey().toString(), each.getValue().toString());

        }
        suite.setParameters(params);
    }
}
```

A sample properties file can look like below:

`name=Jack`

The suite xml file would look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="46224926_Suite" verbose="2">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn46224926.PropertyInjectorListener"/>
    </listeners>
    <test name="46224926_test">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn46224926.TestClass"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

When you run this, you should see an output as below:

```
...
... TestNG 6.12 by Cédric Beust (cedric@beust.com)
...
Hello Jack
PASSED: testMethod("Jack")

===============================================
    46224926_test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================

===============================================
46224926_Suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

As you can see, the suite xml file does not contain any `<parameters>` tag at all. But the `@Test` method still assumes that it will get parameter values via the `@Parameters` annotation. Since our listener takes care of reading all the properties and injecting them as a parameter map, TestNG does not complain.

Comment: That's what I need ! Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

Here, it is the perfect use case for [a data provider](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders).

```
@DataProvider
public Object[][] dp() {
  Properties properties = new Properties();
  properties.load(....);
  ....
  String login = properties.getProperty("data.login");
  String password = properties.getProperty("data.password");
  return new Object[][] { new Object[]{login, password} };
}

@Test(dataProvider = "dp")
public void testSimpleExample(String login, String password) throws Exception {
    Assert.assertTrue(login.equals("login"));
    Assert.assertTrue(password.equals("password"));
}
```

Comment: Hi @juherr, can you help my post here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65285018/set-the-delay-time-for-each-test-in-testng
thanks advance